# JAXB 2.1 implementing Comparable<T> for the generated Class

Tags: java, jaxb2, maven-jaxb2-plugin, jaxb2-basics

- Using Jaxb 2.1 to generate java code from .xsd
- jaxb2-basics plug-in is used
- Wants to have generated Class `Fragment` to implement `Comparable<Fragment>`

```java
public class Fragment implements Serializable, Comparable<Fragment> {
  ...
  public int compareTo(Fragment other) {
    .....
    return 0;
  }
}
```

With the below jaxb bindings file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jxb:bindings xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    xmlns:ci="http://jaxb.dev.java.net/plugin/code-injector"
    xmlns:inheritance="http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/basic/inheritance"
    jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc" 
    jxb:version="2.1">
    <jxb:bindings>
        <jxb:globalBindings>
            <xjc:serializable uid="12343" />
        </jxb:globalBindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="../schemas/Fragment.xsd"
        version="1.0" node="/xs:schema">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='Fragment']/xs:complexType">         
            <inheritance:implements>java.lang.Comparable</inheritance:implements>
            <ci:code>           
public int compareTo(Fragment other) {

    return fragmentVersion.compareTo(other.fragmentVersion);
}
            </ci:code>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

Able to generate class as show below:

```java
public class Fragment implements Serializable, Comparable {
  ...
  public int compareTo(Fragment other) {
    return fragmentVersion.compareTo(other.fragmentVersion);
  }
}
```

**Issue**: As you see, class is generated as `implements Comparable` instead of `implements Comparable<Fragment>`.

Am sure, missing something. Any help to resolve is appreciated.

Comment: Have you actually tried `<inheritance:implements>java.lang.Comparable&lt;Fragment&gt;</inheritance:implements>`?

Comment: @lexicore, I tried `<inheritance:implements>java.lang.Comparable<Fragment></inheritance:imple‌​ments>` which was showing error saying need closing tag. Just tried your suggestion and that works. That should be an answer, and happy to accept it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JAXB2-Basics support generics.

Just use:

```
<inheritance:implements>java.lang.Comparable&lt;Fragment&gt;</inheritance:imple‌​ments>
```

Answer (score 4):

While testing the solution provided by lexicore, noticed another way to resolve the issue:

```
<inheritance:implements><![CDATA[java.lang.Comparable<Fragment>]]></inheritance:implements>
```

Comment: It's actually the same solution. Just a different XML syntax.